# how can i use extracted data from facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

i maked a project, in this part of project i want to save gotten data from graph.facebook.com, now i the sample output of my project that i get from facebook graph api. :

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [message] => Automated XML Site Map Generator
http://pastebin.com/xjJe38dp
                            [id] => 103114753133019_371405176303974
                            [updated_time] => 2013-04-26T05:36:35+0000
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [message] => Simple but powerful DB class
http://pastebin.com/1qgxUrwX
                            [id] => 103114753133019_371404696304022
                            [updated_time] => 2013-04-26T05:34:23+0000
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [message] => Convert Existing DB to Unicode
http://pastebin.com/pHu08cPs
                            [id] => 103114753133019_371404609637364
                            [updated_time] => 2013-04-26T05:33:50+0000
                        )

                )

            [paging] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/103114753133019/feed?fields=message&since=1366954595&access_token=425591634259397|AQumfoxQyU3wAyt3sM37sYM9sp8&limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AexpCrJr7NTOG02uEaXs6pqjd11UjEohZJLjXZrWeYLOsE9hPX7WQTLemXIGMpzdFXEDdDUQj3qdwOqEbmlAfX4TREbZ-3GAfkKiUZ44kHGYLw&__previous=1
                    [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/103114753133019/feed?fields=message&access_token=425591634259397|AQumfoxQyU3wAyt3sM37sYM9sp8&limit=25&until=1366954430&__paging_token=enc_AeyPm9mOsK3T9J0JNkIyQQqxfS7hLDe5GCs-IRLQWPOOzma8v9Rzvw8awxxE0GMQhx-rfs99X7TpUGw5f7HNgPnTKh11WbGC5Yj7GyW7s2VqoA
                )

        )

)
```

as you can see i print theese codes by running :

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/a page id/feed'.$sfield );

$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
// print data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

so now i want to save messages to a file or a database when i want to use **$graphObject** as an array it gives me an error :

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Facebook\GraphObject as array in /home/micengco/public_html/parser/facebook.php on line 34
```

so how i can do this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects have a different way of navigation than array. I think you will need to do something like this:

```
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$backingData = $graphObject->backingData;
$data = $backingData[data][0];
```

In such cases you need to read and comprehend the structure carefully. There will be associative and numerically indexed arrays in such data structures.
What I am doing is above is first fetching the 'backingData' property of the object. Now under this property we have an associative array with a key 'data'. Under that there is a numerically index array that in your example has only one element. If there are multiple elements, you will have to run a loop.

Comment: where can i find the full documentaion

Comment: you mean documentation by Facebook?

Comment: any, from Facebook or anywhere else !!

Comment: @simba: for understanding what data Facebook API is returning for each API call, there is detailed documentation by Facebook. E.g. For Pages API, the link is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page. You can look at other such links. For understanding how it needs to be parsed, there is general rule of understanding how to access object properties and arrays (both numerical and associative). If you look at general PHP tutorials you will be able to understand. BTW, if my answer above helped you, please mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 3):

check out below : (need add "->asArray();" to get output as normal array)

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/a page id/feed'.$sfield );

$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
// print data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

it will not give "backingData:protected" in array.